# chrome.runtime.sendMessage in content script doesn't send message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the following files ([gist](https://gist.github.com/dAnjou/475fd82c4074fd18f795) for easy access):

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "testmessage",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://www.google.com/*"]
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    "eldkfaboijfanbdjdkohlfpoffdiehnb", // PUT YOUR EXTENSION ID HERE
    "foo",
    function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
);
console.log("this is content.js reporting for duty");
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("background.js got a message")
        console.log(request);
        console.log(sender);
        sendResponse("bar");
    }
);
console.log("this is background.js reporting for duty");
```

I can see both *"... reporting for duty"* messages in the respective consoles. But `background.js` doesn't receive a message when http://www.google.com loads. Line 5 in `content.js` prints `undefined` in the console for google.com.

When I run `chrome.runtime.sendMessage("eldkfaboijfanbdjdkohlfpoffdiehnb", "foo");` in the google.com console it shows up in the background.js console.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is over-complicating it. Twice.

First, you don't need to declare to be externally connectable, since you're sending a message from a content script and not the webpage itself.

Second, it's not an external message either. External messages are for connecting different extensions, not messages within one extension.

Your code should look like this:

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    "foo",
    function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("background.js got a message")
        console.log(request);
        console.log(sender);
        sendResponse("bar");
    }
);
```

Comment: great! i knew it!

Comment: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Comment: I was calling the function chrome.runtime.onMessageExtenal.addListener (used for external pages). Changing it to chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener it worked! thanks a lot!!