# response from background in content-script is empty in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple addon script in `content-script` that sends a link to the `background` and it makes a request for that link and it should return a response but it is returning an empty object.

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ imageURL: 'some-image-url.jpg' });

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(data => {
    console.log(data); // its returns {}
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(cb);

function cb(request, sender) {
    fetch(`https:${request.imageURL}`)
        .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
        .then(arrayBuffer => {
            console.log(arrayBuffer); // its log a ArrayBuffer(12354)
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, arrayBuffer);
        });
    return true;
}
```

Before I tried to send the response using `sendResponse` from the `callback(req, sender, sendResponse)` instead of `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` but that didn't work either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596972/chrome-runtime-sendmessage-in-content-script-doesnt-send-message

Comment: 1) you need sendResponse instead of sendMessage, 2) Chrome extensions can't send ArrayBuffer. Although you can serialize it as a byte array, but it'd be super slow and won't work  with large response anyway as the final string length is limited to 64MB (roughly 16MB binary data). In MV3 you'll have to download in an [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) because service worker can't use URL.createObjectURL. Download as `blob()`, use URL.createObjectURL, send the result back into the content script, which will then `fetch` the actual blob data.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm! That was exactly it, I had to convert the arrayBuffer into a string before returning it.